# ViewController is loading a nonexistant nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xib, uistoryboard

Earlier I created a new file called `FTIBTagsActivityViewController` and included a nib. After playing with it for a while, I decided to move the user interface to my main storyboard. So I deleted the .xib file, recreated the UI in my main storyboard, gave the interface the `FTIBTagsActivityViewController` class, and attempted to use.

But, whenever I try to present this view controller:

```
- (UIViewController *) activityViewController
{
    FTIBTagsActivityViewController *tavc = [[FTIBTagsActivityViewController alloc] init];
    tavc.tags = tagsSplit;
    return tavc;
}
```

(This code is returned to the UIActivityViewController and then it attempts to present it modally).

My app crashes with this.

`2013-12-15 18:07:55.982 Mignori[3855:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "FTIBTagsActivityViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'`

It clearly says it has a nib called `FTIBTagsActivityViewController`, but there are two bizarre issues with this:

- That xib no longer exists, and its UI has been moved to my storyboard.
- I actually got rid of every UI element that referenced `FTIBTagsActivityViewController` - That is, to test, I deleted the interface from my storyboard, and my app is still crashing with this message.

I have looked into my project directory and there is no FTIBTagsActivityViewController.xib. It's essentially loading a non-existing xib successfully.

I have tried to clean my project and compile again, but this error is persisting. Help?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData directory?

Comment: You may need to clean & build, reset your simulator and delete the derived data folder before this will work.  I had a similar issue which I resolved the same way.  (I'm assuming you don't reference the nib in your `init` method.)

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm trying your suggestions right now. But yes, I doubled checked and nothing is referencing my view controller in such a way that implied it would come from a nib. EDIT - Deleting the derived data directory and doing a clean build didn't do the trick. Guess I will restart my phone...

Comment: Okay guys, managed to fix it. I'm not really sure what did, so I will write my answer, adding your steps and all. Now my app is crashing for a different reason, haha. But I guess it's progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a bizarre problem, I followed the following steps to get it to work:

1. Emptied the Derived Data folder (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData directory?) as per Rocky's suggestion.
2. Cleaned the project as per Aaron Brager's suggestion.
3. Deleted the app from my phone.
4. Restarted the phone.
5. Ran the project again.

Comment: Glad it worked… don't forget to file a bug report since you have the crash logs :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a uistoryboard using [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"yourstoryboardname" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]].
2. Make sure your viewcontroller has an identifier in your storyboard, and set it to be of the right class
3. Call instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifuer: @"yourId"] on that storyboard created at 1.

Answer (score 0):

Load the viewcontroller using UIstoryboard class. Loading a viewcontroller with alloc init will make it search for anib that os not there. Then if you don't implement loadView, there will be no view.

Comment: I think my new (though unrelated problem) is being caused precisely because I'm doing alloc init. What would be the right way to load a UIViewController using UIStoryboard? I can't seem to find the right method when I type my code and press esc.